# Retrieving object List in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of class object that I created as a variable in my deafault.aspx.cs page

```
List<BoldGauge> boldGauges = new List<BoldGauge>();
```

I create my object in nessacary function and then add the newly created object to the list so I can retrieve it later as needed.

When I attempt loop through the object later the boldGagues count = 0. I assume I need to either add the List to a session variable or session state.

Does anyone know the best approach for this? There could be numerous different types of controls in multiple lists, so if someone could please recommend an approach that is least expensive, and efficient I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where is this line of code? Where are you trying to access it? How are you adding to it?

Comment: @Oded this looks like a followup to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252581/loop-through-class-in-c-sharp-and-change-property-value-of-each-object

Comment: That line of is delcared globally in the default.aspx.cs page:public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
  //const string LayoutSessionKey = "1e38ba85-292e-494e-8f3e-5c8654a9dfef";
  string g_PopupControlId = null;
  static List<BoldGauge> boldGauges = new List<BoldGauge>();

Comment: Yes Kyle, it is a follow up to the previous question I asked

Comment: I add the line: List<BoldGauge> boldGauges = new List<BoldGauge>(); as a global in default aspx. I have a function CreateGauge, where I create the BoldGauge object, then after I create the object, I add it to the global list (boldGauges). In a seperate function I would like to loop through and change values on that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To persist the list across postbacks, you'll need to store the list somewhere.

You can store it in the `Session`, but a more applicable place might be the ViewState.

```
ViewState.Add("GaugesList", boldGauges);
```

then get it back later

```
List<BoldGauges> boldGauges = ViewState["GaugesList"];
```

Note that this is scoped to the page, so if you need the list across pages, use the `Session`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var boldGaug in boldGauges)
{
    //do something..
}
```

Comment: Once out of the function where I add the object to the list, it is no longer accessible. The count is 0, its as if the list is not being retained.